# Forms Authentication for folders with different login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, forms-authentication

[image]

The problem is as follows: 
If a visitor try to access a page in Admin folder he must be redirected to login page located in Admin folder, here I will take his username and password and then I will check this in SQL Server table, if he is authenticated then he will be redirected to Default page and he can access any page in Admin folder, but not any page in User folder
Here is one thing is important and that is login page in Admin folder and login page in User folder are different
Same scenario is for User folder 
Please tell me what is the right way to achieve this functionality 
Please explain your answer

Answer (score 1):

On each page within the Admin folder, as the first line in the C# code of the page - check for the presence of a "IsAllowedAdmin" variable in the session data. If it isn't there, then do a manual redirect to the Admin login page.

When logging into the Admin login page - if the users authenticates ok - then store the IsAllowedAdmin variable to be true in the session data.

And then have a similar thing in the user page....

So...in the admin pages you might have...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["AdminOk"] != null)
    {   
        bool bAdminOk = false;
        try
        {
            bAdminOk = (bool) Session["AdminOk"];
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        if (!bAdminOk)
        {   
            Response.Redirect("~/Admin/login.aspx");
        }

    }
}
```

And then similar (but with a different session variable name) for the user pages...

Comment: can we do it through Forms Authentication technique.

Comment: @Student: FormsAuthentication doesn't have a concept of roles.  The only thing you can do with it is deny anonymous users. The RoleProvider provides the concept of roles, but it doesn't appear that you are using that.

Comment: your code is simple but good one, can we do same work some other way or we have only this method to achieve our objective ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Forms/Membership authentication there is no need to have two different login pages, I don't think this is even possible - instead use a single login page and redirect differently depending on whether your user is an "admin" or a regular user. Forms authentication provides a built in mechanism for this using [Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ab2fxh0.aspx).

To enable roles you need to add a roleManager section to your web.config, i.e.:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlRoleManager">
    <providers>
        <add name="SqlRoleManager" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/"/>
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Then in your authentication sections you can protect pages from normal users, but allow admin users:

```
<authorization>
    <allow roles="Admin"/>
    <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

It's very easy to test in code whether a user is in the admin role (i.e. when deciding where to redirect):

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(user, pass) && Roles.IsUserInRole(user, "Admin"))
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: I am new to `Role` can you provide me links to understant this concept

Comment: @Student: check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647401.aspx, also check msdn in general, there's plenty of updated info there if you search for `membership roles msdn`